# C++: object deleted (created with new) but member function still working (?)

Tags: c++, oop, g++

Just for curiosity and experimenting I wrote following code and now am trying to understand whats happening after delete... why is the cat object still meowing ??

the compiler version I use:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609
```

and compile the code:

```
g++ cat.cpp -pedantic -Wall -o cat
```

With other compilers may crash when calling meou() after delete.

I would like to know

- why is not crashing
- which precautions should I take

the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Cat
{
    public:
        Cat()  { cout << "Cat construct" << endl; }
        ~Cat() { cout << "Cat destruct" << endl; }
        void meow(); 
};

void Cat::meow(void)
{
    cout << "meow..." << endl;
}    

int main()
{
    Cat * pCat = new Cat;    
    pCat->meow();    
    cout << "pCat = " << pCat << endl;    
    delete pCat;    
    pCat = NULL;    
    cout << "pCat = " << pCat << endl;    
    pCat->meow();    
    cout << "why still meowing?!" << endl;    
    return 0;
}
```

the output:

```
Cat construct
meow...
pCat = 0x2147030
Cat destruct
pCat = 0
meow...
why still meowing?!
```

Comment: The `function` doesn't live inside the object and the `pointer` `pCat` still exists. If you add a member function and try to access it after `delete` it will `segfault`

Comment: undefined behavior, it can do anything. Maybe turn on the lights of white house xmas tree, maybe format yr hard drive. It can also appear to work perfectly - this is the most vexing UB as it will fail for sure at the most inconvenient time, like just as the rocket takes off

Comment: undefined behaviour always works.

Comment: @AndreiDamian: A very strange way to put it. I'd say that when you have undefined behaviour, then "it works" and "it doesn't work" are both meaningless statements.

Comment: I wanted to say that when you have undefined behaviour, anything the code would do is "correct", and that means that "it works" as expected.

Answer (score 6):

> why is not crashing

Because dereferencing `nullptr` or accessing a deleted object is undefined behaviour. C++ doesn't have required crashes, but crashes can be the result of undefined behaviour.

> which precautions should I take

That's a rather broad topic. The most important thing in C++ is not to use dynamic allocation if you don't need to. Write:

```
Cat cat;
cat.meow();
```

If you cannot do that, use `std::unique_ptr`:

```
auto cat_ptr = std::make_unique<Cat>();
cat_ptr->meow();
```

If you need a collection, don't use `new[]`. Use `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<Cat> cats;
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Cat>> cat_ptrs;
```